# Using Playwright how to select next td of a given inner text

Tags: html-table, playwright

This one has me baffled.   Basically, using playwright, I'm trying to verify values on a table.   Given, "Cat", I should see if "Dog" exists, or if given "Space", I should see if "Rocket" exists.

I tried

```
const planet = (await page.locator('tr:has(td.col_d:has-text("Saturn")) >> a')).innerText();
```

but that didn't work.  I thought of grabbing all of the innerText on all the , sticking it into an array, then looking for where the initial text is in the Array (Cat) and seeing if the text in the next index is correct (i.e. Dog).  Isn't there an easier way I don't know of yet?

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="labelCol"> Title A < /td>
        <td class="dataCol col02"><span>
            <a href="/00578000000VqXe" title="POS ""</a>
            <a href="/00578000000VqXe" id="lookup00578000000VqXelea1" onblur="LookupHo">Data A</a>
        </td>
        <td class="labelCol">Title X</td>
        <td class="dataCol">Data X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="labelCol" > Cat < /td>
        <td class="dataCol col02">Dog/td >
        <td class="labelCol" > Saturn < /td>
        <td class="dataCol">Jupiter/td > 
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td class="labelCol" > Blue < /td>
        <td class="dataCol col02">Red</td >
        <td class="labelCol" > Reason < /td>
        <td class="dataCol">Space</td > </tr>
            <a href="/00578000000VqXe" id="lookup00578000000VqXelea1" onblur="LookupHo">Rocket</a>
        </td>
    </tr >
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly like this, but you could just assert that 'Dog' is to the right of 'Cat' and 'Rocket' is to the right of 'Space like this if you don't care if they are in the next cell or not.

```
await expect(page.locator(`td:right-of(:text-is("Cat"))`).first()).toHaveText('Dog');
await expect(page.locator(`td:right-of(:text-is("Space"))`).first()).toHaveText('Rocket');
```

Or if Dog needs to immediately follow cat, you could do something like this:

```
const space = page.locator(`td:text-is("Cat")`);
await expect(space.locator(`//following-sibling::td`).first()).toHaveText('Dog');
```